# CLGeocoder rate limited error - alternatives?

Tags: ios, cocoa, clgeocoder

So CLGeocoder api to convert a CLLocation object into a proper address `reverseGeocodeLocation:` . I just noticed as it specifies in the doc that it's rate-limited. A lot of users in our app are seeing the ErrorCode:2 which is due to the rate limit.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/index.html

It would be great if you can suggest some legit, reliable alternatives, or ways to get around this throttle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable alternative to CLGeocoder seems to be the Google Places API for iOS.

There's no way around the rate limit on CLGeocoder, as far as I know.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I will check it out. Thank you.